# Elementary question about Einstein notation

Tags: general-relativity, conventions, notation

I have encountered, in a physics textbook, the following Lagrangian:

$$L=\dfrac{m}{2}g_{ij}(x^k)\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j.$$

I understand that Einstein notation is being used, and therefore there is an implied summation over the indices $i$ and $j$, meaning that:

$$L=\dfrac{m}{2}\sum_{i,j}g_{ij}(x^k)\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j=\dfrac{m}{2}\left(\begin{matrix}\dot{x}^0 & \dot{x}^1 & \dot{x}^2 & \dot{x}^3\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}g_{00} & g_{01} & g_{02} & g_{03} \\ g_{10} & g_{11} & g_{12} & g_{13} \\ g_{20} & g_{21} & g_{22} & g_{23} \\ g_{30} & g_{31} & g_{32} & g_{33}\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}\dot{x}^0 \\ \dot{x}^1 \\ \dot{x}^2 \\ \dot{x}^3\end{matrix}\right).$$

But how should I interpret the index $k$ in the original expression? I have read that, if an index like this is present in an expression and it is not involved in an implicit summation, then it should be assumed that the expression is valid for all values of the index. But this seems very weird in this context, why isn't $\vec{x}$ used instead? I suppose that the intention of the formula is to indicate that the metric depends on the spatial location and time, that is, on the coordinates $\vec{x}=(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)\equiv(t,x,y,z)$.

Comment: Because the arrow notation is usually reserved for 3-vectors, ie that $x^k=(x^0,\vec{x})$

Comment: If one is in the context of Lagrangian mechanics and generalized coordinates, the coordinates $x^k$ might not form a vector space in any particularly meaningful way.

Comment: @OP, the $k$ might also be there because the author might think the reader would mix up the un-bolded/un-arrowed $x$ with a single coordinate (since often $x$ just means a single variable)... But, I think the main point is that since there is no $k$ on the LHS, the $k$ on the RHS can't be doing anything important. I would have written it as: $L=\frac{m}{2}g_{\mu \nu}(x)\dot x^\mu \dot x^\nu$ or as $L = \frac{m}{2}g_{ij}(x)\dot x^i \dot x^j$. But it seems like you know what the author means, despite the clunky notation.

Comment: @hft Thank you very much, that's what I was thinking but it seemed like a weird way to write things so I wasn't quite sure that they didn't mean something else. I would have also written the equation like you did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the index $k$ in the original expression should not be present. I would write
$$L=\dfrac{m}{2}g_{ij}(\mathbf x)\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j$$

where $\mathbf x\equiv (x^1,\ldots, x^N)$ is the list (not *vector*) of coordinates. Some authors use (a variant of) [abstract index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation) in such situations, so by $x^k$ the author means the full list of coordinates, but I find that this introduces unnecessary confusion.

Then again, the symbols $\mathbf x$ or $\vec x$ could lead one to assume that the coordinates constitute some kind of vector, which is generally not true. As is always the case, one could find reasonable ways to complain about any particular choice of notation. The key point is that any potential ambiguity in the notation should be clarified by the author.